# Trama autorización iso 8583-1993 amex

Tags: php, requests

Estoy intentando armar una solicitud de autorización (**ISO 8583-1993**) para Amex, test e-commerce, con los siguientes campos: bitmap, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 14, 19, 22, 24, 25, 26, 32, 42 y 49
Pero no he tenido éxito aún, ¿debo enviarlo todo en formato **ebcdic** o como se describe el dato para cada campo, o empaquetado en **hexadecimal** **ascii**?
¿Alguien podría ayudarme y tendría algún ejemplo de cómo sería?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: asi: https://paiza.io/projects/e/M8Cn6oi7VbCr6qgJLBIzHQ?theme=twilight es solo un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias John por tu respuesta, pero ya lo  he intentado de esa forma, pero tampoco lo logro.

Comment: El tema es que, según la documentación, se debería enviar en ebcdic (hexadecimal ebcdic) por ejemplo **F1F1F0F0 => 1100**, pero al enviarlo tampoco funciona.

Comment: si nos pasas la documentacion seria mas facil ayudarte

Comment: revisando un poco en https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC y modifique el ejemplo, revisarlo de nuevo

Comment: Gracias Jhon por la respuesta, lo probé tampoco funciona, la verdad no se cómo espera el ATS (sitio de pruebas de amex), lo raro que en un ejemplo de "raw request" correcto (supuestamente) que nos pasaron (ej.: F1F1F0F0703425C000408000F0F0F4F0F0F0......), intenté mandar lo mismo, pero ni siquiera llega a destino.

Comment: puede que tu problema este en otro lado, y sea mas de comunicacion que de formato

Comment: también se revisó, pero estaría todo correcto

Comment: sin mayor información no podría decir que es lo que esta fallando.

Comment: ya lo solucioné, el problema estaba en que la longitud de la trama se calculaba sobre los datos planos y en realidad debía calcularse sobre la trama empaquetada y luego a esa longitud (+ 2 por el byte que indica la longitud) se le pasa de decimal a hexa, se la empaqueta y se concatena a la misma la trama:

Comment: $trama_ebcdic = "F1F1F0F0703425C000408000F1F5F3F7F3F9F5F3F1F9F2F3F5F1F0F0F4.......";

$p_trama = pack('H*', $trama_ebcdic);

$len_dec = strlen($p_trama);
$len_dec_full = $len_dec + 2;
$len_hex = dechex($len_dec_full);

$length = strtoupper(str_pad($len_hex, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

$message_iso = pack('H*', $length).$p_trama;

Comment: Excelente felicidades, gracias por compartirlo. 

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, el problema estaba en que la longitud de la trama se calculaba sobre los datos planos y en realidad debía calcularse sobre la trama empaquetada y luego a esa longitud (+ 2 por el byte que indica la longitud) se le pasa de decimal a hexa, se la empaqueta y se concatena a la misma la trama: ￼

`````
$p_trama = pack('H*', $trama_ebcdic); 
$len_dec = strlen($p_trama); 
$len_dec_full = $len_dec + 2; 
$len_hex = dechex($len_dec_full); 
$length = strtoupper(str_pad($len_hex, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)); 
$message_iso = pack('H*', $length).$p_trama;````
`````